# If we have ball $X$ is compact. How to get the set $\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq M\}$ compact? $M$ is a constant number

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Let ball $X$ be a closed unit ball of $X$. We have ball $X$ is compact. How to get the set $\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq M\}$ compact? $M$ is a constant number.

Comment: Hint: closed set in a compact set is compact.

Comment: Another hint, the norm is continuous and $(-\infty,M]$ is closed.

Comment: @yanko Is $\{x\in X:||x||\leq M\}$ a closed subset of ball $X$? How? Thank you!

Comment: Also, keep in mind that if the unit ball is compact in the norm topology, then $X$ is finite dimensional

Comment: yes it is closed in $X$, you can use the second hint or take a convergence sequence..

Comment: You are calling both the space $X$ and the ball in $X$ by the same name?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Let $B$ be the unit ball.

Show that

$$F : B \times [0,M] \to \{x\in X:||x||\leq M \} \\
F(x, t)=tx$$
is continuous.

Comment: how do you know that $B$ is compact? Ah I see his question is not clear.

Comment: @yanko $B$ is compact by hypothesis.

Comment: yes $X$ is a closed unit ball of $X$...

Comment: @yanko He calls it "ball $X$" not $X$. I used $B$ because I think it is more clear.

Comment: Scalar multiplication is continuous in any topological vector space, so the statement in the hint is immediate.

Comment: @ Michael Lee, well the proof is also immediate...

Answer (score 2):

For 'cover compact' you can argue as follows:

Let $B$ denote a closed subset of $X$. Then $X\backslash B$ is an open set in $X$.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a collection of open sets covering $B$ and let $\mathcal{U}^\prime=\mathcal{U}\cup(X\backslash B)$.

Then $\mathcal{U}^\prime$ covers $X$ so some finite subcollection $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{U}^\prime\backslash (X\backslash B)\subseteq\mathcal{U}$ covers $B$.

Comment: you prove that every closed subset of a compact set is closed, but he still need to prove that the given set is closed..

Comment: @yanko So he must prove that a closed unit ball is closed then?

Comment: now he only need to prove that the given set $\{x\in X : \|x\|\leq M\}$ is closed in $X$, either this or I don't understand the question...

Comment: @yanko OK, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Since the norm topology is given by a metric, we have that compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. Thus to show that $\{x\in X \mid \|x\|\leq M\}$ is compact, it suffices to show that every sequence in it has a convergent subsequence. Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence such that $\|x_n\|\leq M$. If $y_n:=x_n/M$, then $(y_n)_n$ is a sequence in the unit ball of $X$. It follows from the compactness of the unit ball that there is $y$ such that $\|y\|\leq 1$ and $y_{n_k}\to y$ for some subsequence $(y_{n_k})_k$. Then $x:=My$ satisifies $\|x\|\leq M$ and
$$
\|x_{n_k}-x\| = \|My_{n_k} - My\| = M\|y_{n_k}-y\|\to 0.
$$